# What is a Java executable's filename extension?

Tags: java, deployment, installation

If C# or VB.NET is distributed in .exe files as MSIL codes, what is Java distributed in? Is there an equivalent form of .exe files for Java (other than .jar files, which I don't think is good for distribution on computers). Or is there a way to save Java intermediate language(?) in an exe like MSIL does? Then distribute it in an exe which is still run by the JRE upon execution.

Comment: Java applications, .jar files, can be run on any platform with JRE. At the same time .NET applications are rather Windows-specific, therefore their code is .exe file which can be run easily on Windows only.

Answer (score 6):

Java "executables" are either `.class` or `.jar` files. It's common to deliver a script (`.bat` file for Windows) with a Java program to run it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to create executable `*.exe` files from `*.jar` files, but this is platform specific and using runnable `*.jar` files is recommended.

For more information on how to make executables with Java please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) thread.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) to install the app.  JWS offers auto-update, splash screens and a lot of other nice functionality.

The user gets desktop shortcuts and menu items if they are requested in the launch file and supported on the OS of the user.  Those shortcuts might have icons as supplied by the developer.

What 'jar', what 'exe'?  Why show the user either when installing a Java rich client?  Using JWS would require Jar files, but the user never sees them.